# Where and How To Define An Application Property? - JHIpster

Tags: jhipster

In Spring Boot, an application property can be defined in application.properties file. For example, a prefix of Rest can be defined as

```
spring.data.rest.basePath=api
```

For JHipster which is based on Spring Boot, I guess that an application property could defined in the application.yml file. But none of the follow approach work for me: a 404 error.

```
spring.data.rest.basePath: api

spring:
    data:
        rest:
            basePath: api
```

The other possibility is the configuration itself doesn't work.

Comment: Hey there. Have you found the solution to set base path in jHipster spring boot? I am also facing the same issue.

Answer (score 10):

I have same problem and finally figured it out!

Quote from Jhipster website:

> Your generated application can also have its own Spring Boot properties. This is highly recommended, as it allows type-safe configuration of the application, as well as auto-completion and documentation within an IDE.
>
> JHipster has generated a ApplicationProperties class in the config package, which is already preconfigured, and it is already documented at the bottom the application.yml, application-dev.yml and application-prod.yml files. All you need to do is code your own specific properties.

In my case, I have set the properties in applicaiton-prod.yml

```
application:
    redis:
        host: vnode1
        pool:
            max-active: 8
            max-idle: 8
            max-wait: -1
            min-idle: 0
        port: 6379
```

In ApplicationProperties class:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "application", ignoreUnknownFields = false)
public class ApplicationProperties {

    public final Redis redis = new Redis();

    public Redis getRedis() {
        return redis;
    }

    public static class Redis {

        private String host = "127.0.0.1";

        private int port = 0;

        public String getHost() {
            return host;
        }

        public void setHost(String host) {
            this.host = host;
        }

        public int getPort() {
            return port;
        }

        public void setPort(int port) {
            this.port = port;
        }

        private Pool pool = new Pool();

        public void setPool(Pool pool) {
            this.pool = pool;
        }

        public Pool getPool() {
            return this.pool;
        }

        public static class Pool {
            private int maxActive = 8;
            private int maxWait = -1;

            public int getMaxIdle() {
                return maxIdle;
            }

            public void setMaxIdle(int maxIdle) {
                this.maxIdle = maxIdle;
            }

            private int maxIdle = 8;
            private int minIdle = 0;


            public void setMaxActive(int maxActive) {
                this.maxActive = maxActive;
            }

            public int getMaxActive() {
                return maxActive;
            }

            public int getMinIdle() {
                return minIdle;
            }

            public void setMinIdle(int minIdle) {
                this.minIdle = minIdle;
            }

            public int getMaxWait() {
                return maxWait;
            }

            public void setMaxWait(int maxWait) {
                this.maxWait = maxWait;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Then I use it as:

```
private final ApplicationProperties.Redis redis;
public RedisConfiguration(ApplicationProperties applicationProperties){
    redis = applicationProperties.getRedis();
}
```

For instance use `max-wait` and `host`:

```
this.redis.getPool().getMaxWait();
this.redis.getHost();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I'm trying to use it in a Service that should provide some configuration for upload paths. When in the service I use
`private final ApplicationProperties.Redis redis;
public RedisConfiguration(ApplicationProperties applicationProperties){
    redis = applicationProperties.getRedis();
}` 
I get the error _viariable might not have been configured._ Because it's a final i guess.

Comment: Seems to me that if you made the fields public, you could change '.getProp()' to simple '.prop';  and so use: this.redis.pool.maxWait; (easier to find and use).  Not clear that using the set/get accessors adds any value.

Answer (score 0):

The `application.yml` should be whit spaces not tabs.

Try like this:

```
spring:
    data:
        rest:
            basePath: api
```

In my application the file is in the path:

```
src\main\resources\config\application.yml
```

Comment: Do you mean a line below another line shall start with a blank space, but not a tab? The generated lines in the application.yml look like pre with one more tab space for me.

Comment: I am working on another issue and will go back to test this one. Thanks for your input.

Comment: What makes you think OP used tabs, not spaces?

Comment: There is how much space I notice in the application.yml file.

Comment: I have tried to put one additional space in front of a new line and four additional spaces in front of a new line without any luck. If what you mean the location is the directory of the application.yml file, I only use the file in the directory src\main\resources\config\application.yml.

Comment: If you see here: https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/master/src/test/resources/config/application.yml
You can also declare keys like this: `jhipster.security.rememberme.key`
Thats not working?

Answer (score 0):

After trying dozens of time how to handle the problem I finally figured out how to make it work. Maybe it will be useful for somebody.

To use prefix for controllers (let's say for example `jh`) we need to use `server.servlet.context-path` and not `spring.data.rest.basePath`.

Link to documentation https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html

So `application.yml` should looks like this:

```
server:
    servlet:
        context-path: /jh
        session:
            cookie:
                http-only: true
```

Answer (score 0):

The information in this link is also useful to help solve.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

After you have built you application config class as per Haifeng Zhang answer above you can then access these properties anywhere by:

@Autowired
private ApplicationProperties redis;

then to access the properties

int myEnvironmentPort = redis.getPort();