# Displaying APIs of Spring Data Rest

Tags: jhipster

After adding Spring Data Rest to a JHipster generated project, how to make those Rest APIs viewable in addition of APIs on the controller level?

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "api/myEntities", path = "api/myEntites")
```

I also try "/api/myEntities".

In Spring Data Rest, I would be able to see those Rest APIs something like

```
/api/myEntities/search/<method name>
```

The following is the SwaggerConfiguration class in my project. I don't see how I can customize it to show APIs from Spring Data Rest.

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
@Profile("!"+Constants.SPRING_PROFILE_PRODUCTION)
public class SwaggerConfiguration implements EnvironmentAware {

  private final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SwaggerConfiguration.class);

  public static final String DEFAULT_INCLUDE_PATTERN = "/api/.*";

  private RelaxedPropertyResolver propertyResolver;

@Override
public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
    this.propertyResolver = new RelaxedPropertyResolver(environment, "swagger.");
}

/**
 * Swagger Springfox configuration.
 */
@Bean
public Docket swaggerSpringfoxDocket() {
    log.debug("Starting Swagger");
    StopWatch watch = new StopWatch();
    watch.start();
    Docket docket = new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
        .apiInfo(apiInfo())
        .genericModelSubstitutes(ResponseEntity.class)
        .forCodeGeneration(true)
        .genericModelSubstitutes(ResponseEntity.class)
        .directModelSubstitute(org.joda.time.LocalDate.class, String.class)
        .directModelSubstitute(org.joda.time.LocalDateTime.class, Date.class)
        .directModelSubstitute(org.joda.time.DateTime.class, Date.class)
        .directModelSubstitute(java.time.LocalDate.class, String.class)
        .directModelSubstitute(java.time.ZonedDateTime.class, Date.class)
        .directModelSubstitute(java.time.LocalDateTime.class, Date.class)
        .select()
        .paths(regex(DEFAULT_INCLUDE_PATTERN))
        .build();
    watch.stop();
    log.debug("Started Swagger in {} ms", watch.getTotalTimeMillis());
    return docket;
}

/**
 * API Info as it appears on the swagger-ui page.
 */
private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
    return new ApiInfo(
        propertyResolver.getProperty("title"),
        propertyResolver.getProperty("description"),
        propertyResolver.getProperty("version"),
        propertyResolver.getProperty("termsOfServiceUrl"),
        propertyResolver.getProperty("contact"),
        propertyResolver.getProperty("license"),
        propertyResolver.getProperty("licenseUrl"));
}
```

}

Comment: try looking at    xx.xx.config.apidoc.SwaggerConfiguration.java

Comment: @pmverma Thanks for the info. I can't see how to change the class to get newly added APIs.

Answer (score 0):

In `xx.xx.config.apidoc.SwaggerConfiguration.java`

Following is the default pattern to include in SwaggerConfiguration which will display API in your administration tab.

`public static final String DEFAULT_INCLUDE_PATTERN = "/api/.*";`

And following line from the same class

`.paths(regex(DEFAULT_INCLUDE_PATTERN))`

added the above pattern.

So you can add another one of your own, examining the `Spring Data Rest` api pattern. And add that api pattern in the `paths()` function like as above one.

**Here I am talking with *jhipster 2.18.0***

Comment: Thanks for the info. I get it. It still doesn't work. I put more related details in my question.

Comment: @vic Did you tried this: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#getting-started.basic-settings

Comment: try adding `spring.data.rest.basePath=/api`

Comment: Actually, I had tried to have the path configuration in the application.yml file. It doesn't work. I had put a question on the setup (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31527868/where-and-how-to-define-an-application-property-jhipster).