# How to JHipster Springboot Configuration programmatically?

Tags: spring-boot, jhipster

I already tried autowiring SpringBootConfiguration but nothing was found from my test project. I need to check a field I added in application-dev.properies and see if its true or false before executing some tests.

Comment: Please clarify your question, a verb is pissing in title and description is quite obscure for me.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou Perhaps you meant "missing"? :)

Comment: Its actually been answered ... Just found it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31527868/where-and-how-to-define-an-application-property-jhipster

Comment: Check JHipster official doc https://www.jhipster.tech/common-application-properties/ also Spring Boot doc

Answer (score 0):

It was answered before:

[Where and How To Define An Application Property? - JHIpster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31527868/where-and-how-to-define-an-application-property-jhipster)

However please note to uncomment

```
  application:
```

In the properties file. And also its best to create an object and be sure to instantiate that object yourself so it is not null. It should be a final object as shown.

Another example is found here:  https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster/blob/master/jhipster-framework/src/main/java/io/github/jhipster/config/JHipsterProperties.java